# Does the huge flier in the final mission in Wings of Liberty spawn more fliers?

Tags: starcraft-2

I saw the huge flier, but since it didn't attack, I left it alone.
After a while, I think I saw it spawn a flier or two. Is that what it does?

So, I should destroy it first chance I get, right?

Comment: @Kyralessa - how would you phrase the title?

Comment: make the title more descriptive -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Leviathan does, in fact, spawn more zerg flyers, mutalisks especially (or exclusively? Either way...).

Try and make sure you have the artifact ready for when the Leviathan finally makes its appearance, and remember - it's "so high up in the air" that ground units can't attack it at all. You'll need a load of vikings, wraiths, and battlecruisers to bring that thing down.

*Point of Interest* -- If you had chosen the "Destroy the Orbital Platform" mission instead, you would have had to fight the beastie on that level as a bonus objective.